# Highstock type 'candlestick' - Change bordercolors

Tags: highcharts, candlestick-chart

Couldn't find this in the documentation.

Only thing I found is "upColor and Color" which doesn't even target the candles only.

Found no way to get rid of those black borders or even change the tick color.

How come there is no option candlestick.tickColor or bordercolor?

Anyone?

Comment: If you can use highcharts.box instead of highstock.candlestick you can get a lot more styling options:  http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/box-plot-styling/

Comment: thats interesting... thanks senior web developer at apple :D

Answer (score 1):

In `candlestick` series type you should use `lineColor` and `upLineColor` properties:

```
series: [{
    type: 'candlestick',
    upLineColor: 'red',
    lineColor: 'red',
    data: [
        [0, 7, 2, 0, 4],
        [1, 1, 4, 2, 8],
        [2, 3, 3, 9, 3]
    ]
}]
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/2L0dqnwa/

API:

https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/series.candlestick.lineColor

https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/series.candlestick.upLineColor